# in c we are using abs to find the absolute value,in c# what we are using for that purpose?

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Solution
{

    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < q; a0++)
        {
            string[] tokens_x = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_x[0]);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_x[1]);
            int z = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_x[2]);
             if(abs(z-x) > abs(z-y))
             {
         Console.WriteLine("Cat B\n");
        }
        else if(**

    abs(z-x) < abs(z-y))
            {

**
            Console.WriteLine("Cat A\n");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse C\n");
        }

        }
```

How can I get the absolute value of a number in C#?

Comment: Why not try google first instead of asking here??

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for `Math.Abs`?

```
...
else if (Math.Abs(z-x) < Math.Abs(z-y))) {
  ... 
}
```

You can get rid of annoying `Math.` class prefix with a help of `using static`:

```
using static System.Math;

... 

else if (Abs(z-x) < Abs(z-y))) {
  ... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Math.Abs`

The `Math` static class contains many math operations.

Answer (score 1):

As other answerers already pointed out, you are probably searching for [Math.Abs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ke8e73(v=vs.110).aspx). Example from the docs:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      decimal[] decimals = { Decimal.MaxValue, 12.45M, 0M, -19.69M, 
                             Decimal.MinValue };
      foreach (decimal value in decimals)
         Console.WriteLine("Abs({0}) = {1}", value, Math.Abs(value));

   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Abs(79228162514264337593543950335) = 79228162514264337593543950335
//       Abs(12.45) = 12.45
//       Abs(0) = 0
//       Abs(-19.69) = 19.69
//       Abs(-79228162514264337593543950335) = 79228162514264337593543950335
```

However, since you did not know about this and did not find it either, you could have solved this yourself without great problems, like:

```
public static decimal Absolute(decimal value) {
    return (value < 0) ? -value : value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `System.Math.Abs`. `Math` is a static class. The usual way of doing it was:

```
using System;

// ...

int result = Math.Abs(z - x);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Since C#6.0 you have the additional possibility of `using static`

```
using System;
using static System.Math;
using static System.Console;

// ...

int result = Abs(z - x);
WriteLine(result);
```

Explanation: The language C# does not by itself define an `abs`-function. However, there is a static class `System.Math` in the .NET class library which contains a lot of static math-functions. Among them the `Abs` function with overloads for different numeric types.